# What is an "exp" red texture map?

Tags: texturing, image

I have a base color, normal and an "exp" texture map for a CSGO model. It is kind of a weird red texture and I have no idea how to correctly set it up. Thanks.

Comment: I have no answer to this, but I also have a random exp texture. Blender defined it as a BL texture though.